# How does a web server handle multiple requests at the same time

Tags: apache, iis, nginx

How does a web server handle multiple requests at the same time?

what happen at web server when it get requests? how it handle multiple requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how a web server(apache) handles multiple HTTP requests, on the code level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628165/how-a-web-serverapache-handles-multiple-http-requests-on-the-code-level)

Comment: Following links will help you to understand it at high level.    For IIS6 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524901(v=vs.90).aspx                                                      For IIS7 and above : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.140).aspx